# org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelFuture.awaitUninterruptibly() hangs when closing a channel using SSL/TLS

Tags: java, nio, netty

This problem occurs if our backend uses an `SSLHandler` while the frontend does not:

When the frontend connects to the backend, an (expected) exception is thrown in the backend by a `ChannelHandler`: "`SSLException`: not an SSL/TLS record: 47455...". Then, the backend tries to close the channel that was responsible for this exception but `ChannelFuture.awaitUninterruptibly()` returned by `Channel.close()` hangs indeterminately. Also, there a no exceptions in the frontend. The `ChannelFuture` of `Channel.write()` completes without any problems.

How is it possible to force a close on this channel in the backend and why does `Channel.close()` hang?

EDIT:

[Server in the frontend](http://pastebin.com/3BbZz6VG)

[Server in the backend](http://pastebin.com/5SUjheeP)

`StatefulTcpServer.haltConnection(String connectionId)` hangs because `future.awaitUninterruptibly();` does not return.

We are using version 3.3.1.Final.

EDIT 2:

[Thread dump](http://pastebin.com/yGLpfTFT) in the backend when `ChannelFuture.awaitUninterruptibly()` hangs

Comment: Could you show us the code and also include a thread-dump?

Comment: I added the source code of the server classes in the frontend and the backend.

Comment: The problem would be easier to understand if you mentioned that you're using Netty in your code (at least that's whzt the thread dump appears to show)